# Pass SSIS Object to child SSIS package

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I tried to pass a SSIS Object (actually a DataSet) to a child package. I got an error which tells me that I am not allowed to do that. Why can't I do it ? This never happens in a programming language. Are there any workarounds for this ?

Thanks.

**EDIT -**

```
Error - Property "Value" with type "Object" of variable "User::MY_DATA_SET" 
can not be exported to the configuration file.
```

Comment: To get the best use out of SO, you should post both the code you are using and the exact error message itself.

Comment: @ChrisLively - Actually, there is no code really. But, I can include the error message.

Comment: Some hope over here - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1524372-364-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS does not allow you to do this. BUT, there is a way to still do it ! Try the instructions at the link below -

http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2009/10/03/passing-an-object-from-a-parent-package-to-a-child/

Keep in mind that you should NOT include the child variable in the read or read/write section of your script task. That will cause the error -

```
A deadlock was detected while trying to lock variables “User::ParentVariable” 
for read access and variables “User::ChildVariable” for read/write access. 
A lock cannot be acquired after 16 attempts. The locks timed out.
```

As an aside, read the comments below the post. You can avoid the errors the posters were getting.